# Post on Facebook Page's timeline using graph api from Apex Salesforce

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, salesforce, apex-code

I am posting a content to my page in facebook. I have created an app for my account and also created a page with admin access. I have written logic to post my content to facebook page. My content is getting posted to my page under '**post a page**' section but it is not getting posted on the '**Page's Timeline**'. Please suggest. Am a newbie in integration part. Suffering with this for the past 1 week.

Regards

Indhu

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use a **Page Token** instead of a User Token. Information about the Tokens and how to generate them:

- https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/access-tokens/
- http://www.devils-heaven.com/facebook-access-tokens/
- http://www.devils-heaven.com/extended-page-access-tokens-curl/

Comment: I have used my page token to post on the page. I have used page_Id/Feed to post on page. My content is getting posted on page but it is getting posted on '**post to page**' section but it is not posting on '**Page Timeline**'

Comment: then you are not using a page token, for sure.